# Cannot click on the jQuery menu items

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have created a `jQuery` menu which will open when clicking on a small icon. This menu contains some links which are clickable and one link which will do some js actions and create a new textbox within the same menu. But when I click on the links, the menu automatically closes. So even if a textbox is displayed, it cannot be seen until we click that icon again to see the menu.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/W2exq/1/

I have used some `jQuery` codes to show and hide the menu and also to display a textbox. So how can I maintain the menu opened, unless we click outside the menu to close it?
Please let me know if you need any other things.

---

HTML:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://tharunjose.com/stack/style.css" />
</head>
<div class="notes">
    <div class="noteTooltip">
        This link is for the special purpose of the main site.<hr />
        <a class="noteEdit" id="add_btn" href="#">Edit note</a>
        <a class="noteTrash" href="#"></a>
    </div>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
.notes{
    position:relative;
    width:16px;
    height:16px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background:url(http://tharunjose.com/stack/images/icons.png) no-repeat scroll -228px -34px transparent;
}
.notes:hover{
    cursor:pointer;
    background-position:-207px -34px;
}
.noteTooltip{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:25px;
    left:-10px;
    width:130px;
    text-align:left;
    line-height:18px;
    border:2px solid #363636;
    z-index:9999;
    background:#fbfbfb;
    -webkit-border-radius:3px;
    -moz-border-radius:3px;
    border-radius:3px;
    padding:10px 10px 6px 10px;
    cursor:auto;
}
.noteTooltip:before{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    top:-10px;
    left:10px;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    border-left:5px solid transparent;
    border-right:5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom:8px solid #000;
    z-index:9999;
}
.noteEdit{
    color:#3ba5d5;
    text-decoration:none;
    float:left;
}
.noteTrash{
    display:block;
    float:right;
    padding:6px;
    background:url(http://tharunjose.com/stack/images/icons.png) no-repeat scroll -20px -106px transparent;
}​
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $(document).click(function(e) {
        $(".createNew, .username, .notes, .pageHelp, .buttons").removeClass("open");
    });
    $(".createNew, .username, .notes, .pageHelp, .buttons").click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation(); // this prevents it closing via document.click
        $(this).toggleClass("open");
    });


       var handler_func = function () {
        var i = (typeof this.rel != 'undefined') && (this.rel - 0) == this.rel ? this.rel : 0;
        var e = document.createElement('input');
        e.type='text';
        e.width=40;
        e.name = 'added'+i;
        this.rel = i+1;
        this.parentNode.appendChild(e);
        return false;       
        }

        var add_btn = document.getElementById('add_btn');
        if(add_btn.attachEvent)
              add_btn.attachEvent('onClick', handler_func);
        else if(add_btn.addEventListener) //Firefox & company
              add_btn.addEventListener('click', handler_func, false);
});
```

​

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stop the "click" event from bubbling up the DOM and causing it to close your "popup" menu.

This is imperfect (allows you to create multiple text elements, I'm not going to do all your work :P ) but should give you a good starting point:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $(document).click(function(e) {
        $(".createNew, .username, .notes, .pageHelp, .buttons").removeClass("open");
    });

    $(".createNew, .username, .notes, .pageHelp, .buttons").click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation(); // this prevents it closing via document.click
        $(this).toggleClass("open");
    });

    $(".noteTooltip").click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation(); //stop the onclick call bubbling up the DOM.
        e.preventDefault(); //stop the onclick call bubbling up the DOM.
    });

    $("#add_btn").click(function(event) {
       var i = (typeof this.rel != 'undefined') && (this.rel - 0) == this.rel ? this.rel : 0,
           element = document.createElement('input');

       event.stopPropagation();  //stop the onclick call bubbling up the DOM.
       element.type='text';
       element.width=40;
       element.name = 'added'+i;
       this.rel = i+1;
       this.parentNode.appendChild(element);
       return false;   
    });

});
```

[`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

A [blog post](http://bmarti44.wordpress.com/2011/12/26/javascript-event-bubbling-explained/) on event bubbling also.

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/W2exq/12/).

​

Comment: Thanks, What's the difference from this answer and the one above?

Comment: Not so much, I didn't see the answer above while writing mine. I just also updated your add_btn click event to use the jQuery handler also to keep your code more consistent.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a click listener on .noteTooltip:

```
$(".noteTooltip").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: I have used the same technique for a customized checkbox inside the menu. But the checkbox is not functioning when I used this code for the checkbox drop down menu not to exit when I click the checkbox.

Comment: Then you should have added a container to wrap your checkbox and add the click listener to that container.

Comment: @99tharun please read up on event.stopPropagation() link is provided in my answer. There is more than enough of a code example here to fix your issue (in both answers supplied) you need to grasp an understanding of how the click event can bubble up the DOM elements to gain understanding on how this is affecting your current implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to stop the event propogation when the `Edit Note` is clicked and also when you click on the text box that is added.

Just pass the event in your `handler_func`

```
var handler_func = function (evt)
```

and before the `return false;` in the same function add

```
e.onclick = function(e1) {
              e1.stopPropagation();
           }
evt.stopPropagation();
```

And that will solve the problem.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/W2exq/14/)